# Store value of dynamic button after click

Tags: java, android-studio

in my "apri_hub" method I would like to keep the value of the clicked button and then use it in another class.
I tried different solutions, but all of them give me the error "Variable is accessed within inner class"
How can I solve?

```
 private void apri_hub(List<Button> bt)
{
    for(Button button : bt)
    {
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //cosa deve fare onCLICK

                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HubLocaleActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The list of buttons that I will use in the main are dynamically created in another method, so they do not have id, or other trace in the xml

Comment: what value you want to keep when clicking buttons ?

Comment: just the text, the problem is that the buttons are created dynamically, so they do not have ids and they do not have any trace in the XML

Comment: If you want to use just the text of the button (string) why don't you use intent's putExtra method and pass in the text of the button?

Comment: you don't need to iterate through the buttons when you are creating the button just implement the setOnClickListener there you will automatically get  the button text when it get clicked.

Comment: I would have a List of Button objects. When you dynamically create a button, add it to the List.  You'll have to pass the List or a reference to MainActivity to your other class.  If you're in a Fragment, you can use getActivity() and call your MainActivity's public methods.

Comment: @Steven i tried something like                                                                               Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HubLocaleActivity.class);                                          i.putExtra(button) , but i got the same error

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a bundle that will contain all parameters that you need to pass to the second activity

Put an int which is your id into the new Intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("key", 1); //Your id
intent.putExtras(b); //Put your id to your next Intent
startActivity(intent);
finish();

// Then grab the id in your new Activity:
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
int value = -1; // or other values
if(b != null)
    value = b.getInt("key");
```

Comment: I already try this solution but i got error - "Variable is accessed within inner class"

Comment: @Mattek can you declar your variable as final ?

Comment: @Mattek this article explains the issue and provides some solutions http://blog.brendanlacanette.com/2015/08/variable-is-accessed-within-inner-class.html